# if stamement not working against db query

Tags: php, database, if-statement

I am running the code below but can't get the if statement to work. I want to be able to remove the div if there is no content and if there is then to display it but at the moment it either removes it all if one db entry is empty instead of just removing the 1 empty row.

```
             <?php 
     $con = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
     extract($_GET);
     { $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM links ORDER by id ");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

     if ($section=""){
     echo"";
     }
     elseif ($section="a"){
     echo"<div class=\"page-header\">" . $row['section'] . "\</div>";
     }


      echo "<div class=\"links-wrap\">
         <div class=\"links-box\">
         <div class=\"links-image\"><img src=\"images/links/" . $row['img1'] . "\"></div>
         <div class=\"links-site-txt\">" . $row['link1'] . "</div>
         <div class=\"links-desc\">" . $row['desc1'] . "</div>
         </div>
         <div class=\"spacer-left\"></div>
         <div class=\"links-box\"></div>
         <div class=\"spacer-left\"></div>
         <div class=\"links-box\"></div>
          </div>";}}
      mysqli_close($con);
       ?>
```

Comment: Where did you set `$section`?

Answer (score 0):

To compare value by `if` or `elseif` `==` is required not `=`. `=` generally use to assign value to a variable. Change your codes like below.

```
$con = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
extract($_GET);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM links ORDER by id ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $section = $row['section'];
    if ($section == ""){
        echo "";
    }
    elseif ($section == "a"){
        echo"<div class=\"page-header\">" . $row['section'] . "\</div>";
    }

    echo "<div class=\"links-wrap\">
     <div class=\"links-box\">
     <div class=\"links-image\"><img src=\"images/links/" . $row['img1'] . "\"></div>
     <div class=\"links-site-txt\">" . $row['link1'] . "</div>
     <div class=\"links-desc\">" . $row['desc1'] . "</div>
     </div>
     <div class=\"spacer-left\"></div>
     <div class=\"links-box\"></div>
     <div class=\"spacer-left\"></div>
     <div class=\"links-box\"></div>
      </div>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I now get Notice: Undefined variable: section on line 20?

Comment: Because you did not define `$section`. Define it first top of the code.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to php and not sure what needs to be done to define it. It should pull the value from the db?

Comment: Is there a way to change it so that if $section is populated ie has anything in the value it will display rather than have to say == "a" for instance?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 $con = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 extract($_GET);
 { $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM links ORDER by id ");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 if ( $section == "" ){ //double equality for condition check
 echo "";
 }
 else if ($section == "a" ){
 echo"<div class=\"page-header\">" . $row['section'] . "\</div>";
 }


  echo "<div class=\"links-wrap\">
     <div class=\"links-box\">
     <div class=\"links-image\"><img src=\"images/links/" . $row['img1'] . "\"></div>
     <div class=\"links-site-txt\">" . $row['link1'] . "</div>
     <div class=\"links-desc\">" . $row['desc1'] . "</div>
     </div>
     <div class=\"spacer-left\"></div>
     <div class=\"links-box\"></div>
     <div class=\"spacer-left\"></div>
     <div class=\"links-box\"></div>
      </div>";}}
  mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```